# Как быстро воспроизвести команды, которые набирал до перезагрузки python консоли в pycharm

Tags: python, django, pycharm

Работаю на pycharm. Создаю класс User, загружая консоль с проектом и тестирую класс командами типа:

```
from mainapp.models import User, Event, StartTime, Notification, UnviewedReminder
a = User.objects.get(username='test')
r = UnviewedReminder.objects.create(user=a, start_time=StartTime.objects.last())
n = Notification.objects.create(user=a, text='first_notification')
a.get_notifications_and_reminders()
```

На последней получаю ошибку, меняю класс User, и мне нужно его опять протестировать.
Сейчас для этого я после каждого изменения перезагружаю консоль и опять ввожу те же команды. Это жутко не удобно, даже c клавишей "стрелочка вверх". Как быстро воспроизвести команды, которые набирал до перезагрузки? Или может быть есть другие способы быстрее тестировать класс?

Comment: А почему бы не написать скрипт и не выполнять его каждый раз?

Comment: @V-Mor Не могу писать сразу скрипт, потому-что хочу получать отзыв от каждой команды. Вот если бы можно было из консоли в нормальном формате скопировать мои последние команды, возможно это мне решило проблемы

Comment: Что Вы подразумеваете под отзывом? Ваши команды, вроде как, не подразумевают вывода чего-либо на экран

Comment: @V-Mor вывожу значение каждой переменной, смотрю, чтобы не было ошибок и тд

Answer (score 0):

Нашел историю своих команд в консоли pycharm, что в принципе решает мою проблему[image: введите сюда описание изображения]